# 2 Reverse DNS towards same IP. Is it bad?

Tags: reverse-dns

We are moving our mail server to Amazon Cloud
We currently have a reverse DNS for our mail server with current provider.
When moving to Amazon, we have to cancel that one and get Amazon to create a reverse DNS for our domain towards the amazon IP.
Now i would like to create 2 Reverse DNS records towards the same Amazon IP.
Reason beeing that one is getting faded out and a new will be intreduced over the next year.
Question.. Is it ok in this situation to ask Amazon to create Reverse DNS for 2 subdomains towards the same IP?
Thanks for your time
Regards
Morten

Answer (score 0):

Yes. An IP address can have multiple PTRs (pointing to multiple DNS names). This is somewhat uncommon but by standard.

Do make sure that all these DNS names resolve back to the same IP address (by their A record), otherwise FcrDNS will fail.